# Associate the DocuSign envelope to opportunity using the API

Tags: apex, soap-api, docusign

I'm trying to send envelopes using the API and am receiving a bug where it creates the status and is working with Salesforce, but isn't associating it to the opportunity.

I'm getting an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Any ideas or help would be amazing. 
Thanks.

Comment: FYI, [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/docusignapi) provides technical support all docusign api questions. It's worth giving a shot there too.